# Obtaining the page path without using REQUEST_URI within the themes functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php
global $wp;
    if(!function_exists('my_custom_query_vars')) {
        function my_custom_query_vars() {
        add_rewrite_tag( '%hello%', '(true|false|0|1)' );
        echo $wp->request;
    }
}
?>
```

The `$wp` variable is not defined here yet. I want to be able to enable the rewrite tag for a specific page, which is why I am interested in the URI. I don't know if it is bad practice to use `$SERVER["REQUEST URI"]` in this context.

Is it possible to get the path of the page the WordPress way?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the page or post id you can use get_permalink($id);
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink